# Underground Electrical Outlet

Tags: electrical, outdoor

I have a 240v outlet in my front yard that is rarely used.  It is a pain to mow around and I have never had a need of it (installed by previous owners to power a refrigerated truck).  I do not want to remove it altogether as It could be useful in the future.

Does anyone know of a solution to place the outlet below ground, maybe in a dry box that could easily be opened and connected to when needed?

Comment: There's probably no box available that can be "easily" opened, unless your definition of "easily" is removing a few screws. You'll want to search for a "handhole" or "underground pull box"

Comment: I would think that something along the lines of those water main boxes but completely enclosed and waterproof. Condensation can be delt with by installing a switch or convenient breaker in the house.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should start by installing a lockout on the breaker that feeds this: so you can turn it off completely.  Then you've got your choice of trying to install a vault to hold the device (with attendant moisture problems), or simply disconnecting the outlet, capping the wires and throwing dirt over.  Leave some bright colored tape above it, and a note in the breaker box, to aid in a *future treasure hunt.*

Comment: I found a 6 in square outdoor electrical box at my local hardware store.  I removed the outlet and capped the wired, ran them through a knockout in the box and loaded it up with silicone.  Sealed the box and left it exposed and ground level so it's easily visible where it's located.

Comment: @PrestonS I still recommend you "lock out" that particular breaker... until it is needed again.  No telling when moisture will get into your box.